# ComboBox fixed size with growToLongestValue for content list

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I want to keep the field small (fixed max width) but get the content of the list grow to the longest value when dropdown shows. Is there any way to achieve this?

Here in this example, the scroll hide the last part of the longest value.

http://jsfiddle.net/2P4x4/

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    style: 'margin-left:5px',
    fieldLabel: 'MyLabel',
    labelSeparator: ' ',
    growToLongestValue: true,
    matchFieldWidth: false,
    //grow: true,
    store: [
        'longest_valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeabcdeX',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'auto_scroll_to_this_selected_element',
        'l_value_2'
    ]
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I finally found to solve this problem. I overridden the css of exjs to add padding to the left of each

elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/2P4x4/2/

```
.x-boundlist-item {
    padding: 0 20px 0 6px;
}
```

There is always 20px more to the right even if there is no scroll but at least the content is not hidden by the scroll bar when present.

Answer (score 0):

Change the property values as below:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    style: 'margin-left:5px',
    fieldLabel: 'MyLabel',
    labelSeparator: ' ',
    growToLongestValue: false,
    //matchFieldWidth: false,
    //grow: true,
    store: [
        'longest_valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeabcdeX',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'l_value_2',
        'auto_scroll_to_this_selected_element',
        'l_value_2'
    ]
});
```

Comment: Like I said, I need in my case keep the width of the field to a maximum size in width and expand the drop down list expanding to largest value in it.